# UploadProgressChanged Event Not Being Called

Tags: c#, file-upload, uri

I'm uploading files using the UploadFilesAsync method shown below.

```
var wc = new WebClient();
Uri myUri = new Uri(uriString);
wc.UploadFileAsync(myUri, "POST", filePath);
wc.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_UploadProgressChanged);
wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadFileCompleted);
```

My UploadFileCompleted event handler is called, but for some reason the UploadProgressChanged event handler is never called.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
wc.UploadFileAsync(myUri, "POST", filePath);
wc.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_UploadProgressChanged);
wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadFileCompleted);
```

For:

```
wc.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_UploadProgressChanged);
wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadFileCompleted);
wc.UploadFileAsync(myUri, "POST", filePath);
```

> You are binding the event **AFTER** the UploadFileAsync call, you must bind event handlers
>    first.

**MSDN EXAMPLE:**

```
// Sample call: UploadFileInBackground2("http://www.contoso.com/fileUpload.aspx", "data.txt")
public static void UploadFileInBackground2 (string address, string fileName)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    Uri uri = new Uri(address);

    client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler (UploadFileCallback2);

     // Specify a progress notification handler.
     client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
    client.UploadFileAsync (uri, "POST", fileName);
    Console.WriteLine ("File upload started.");
}
```

Comment: When the UploadFileCompletedEventHandler fires, it the file uploaded on target destionation?

Answer (score 0):

You should first add eventHandlers and then call the method which will fire them.

```
wc.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_UploadProgressChanged);
wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadFileCompleted);
wc.UploadFileAsync(myUri, "POST", filePath);
```

Comment: Tried this, and the progress changed event is still never called.

Comment: Are you sure that upload works? Do you get the file on server after you upload it?