# UploadProgressChanged Event Not Being Called (More Details)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, file-upload, webclient

This question is exact duplicate of this one:
[UploadProgressChanged Event Not Being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692301/uploadprogresschanged-event-not-being-called)

Some more details:

1. I am using Unity 2018.2.13f1
2. The API is a POST method
3. Video attachment is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G_OAwU6WjpGN77ESGdcVnMCkbjA5QQTn/view?usp=sharing)
4. Code sample:

```
    void Upload(string url, string filePath)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        var authorizationHeaderValue = "Bearer: " + token;
        webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue);
        webClient.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(WebClientUploadProgressChanged);
        webClient.UploadFileCompleted += WebClientUploadCompleted;
        webClient.UploadFileAsync(new System.Uri(url), filePath);
    }

    void WebClientUploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Upload {0}% complete. " + e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    void WebClientUploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string reply = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
        Debug.Log(reply);
    }
```

The original question was asked 6 years back, and it still doesn't have a solution. Anyone has a workaround?

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: I have tried a 3 mb file as well as a 93 mb file

Comment: could you add your complete code anyway please?

Comment: Added code sample in the question