# Uploading large files using UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webclient, unitywebrequest

I have an API to upload file to Microsoft Azure blob storage. Users can be uploading large files. Webclient handles files automatically, but its progress change event doesn't work.
Here is a link to that issue though:
[UploadProgressChanged Event Not Being Called (More Details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300258/uploadprogresschanged-event-not-being-called-more-details)

How do I use UnityWebRequest to upload large file without reading entire file into memory first?

Comment: I guess you can't. [UnityWebRequest.Put](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-UploadingRawData.html) and [UnityWebRequest.Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) need `byte[]` as inputs.

Comment: That's the HLAPI, Uploading streamed data is supported by their LLAPI: [Creating Upload Handlers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-CreatingUploadHandlers.html)

Comment: @Foggzie as far as I can see in their example they also `// ... fill payload with data ...` (which is a `byte[]`) before they start the upload

Comment: That's what the constructor accepts but it's still uploaded as a stream. _"This buffer is copied internally into native code memory and then used by the UnityWebRequest system when the remote server is ready to accept body data._".  From the [UnityWebRequests page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) it states: "_It also supports high-demand features such as chunked HTTP requests, *streaming POST/PUT operations*, and...._"

Comment: @Foggzie But we still have to read entire file as byte first, and pass it as parameter right?

Comment: Yea, Unity's API requires the entire `byte[]` to be present and _afterwards_, handles streaming it through a Web Request.  I'm not aware of a solution for streaming the contents of a file on disc into a network request that is streaming those chunks across the network at the same time without making multiple Web Request objects.